# Login filter java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a simple implementation of login filter.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session == null || session.getAttribute("loggedInUser") == null) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {}

    }
```

When I go to any registered page(i.e. `/account?id=1`) without session attribute `loggedInUser`, filter works fine. It redirects me to login page.
But if I go to non-exists page (i.e. `/blablabla.html`), filter redirects me to login page again. Is there any method to get 404 error on entering non-exists pages and redirect to `/login` on exists?

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in the requirement: you filter all requests to deny access to guests but still want the request to be processed if it's a 404. This would be conceptually wrong: a 404 is still an applicative response in the sense that it gives the user a view of the internals of the system - so the user must be authorized before knowing that something is or is not there.

Another option is splitting your app in a public and a private zone:

- `/public/style.css`
- `/public/app.js`
- ...
- `/private/customer/123`
- `/private/oder/8932`
- ...

and just filter requests in the private zone.

<sub>Note: if you are concerned about the beauty of the URL consider that the `/private/` prefix is not a requirement. The filter can be attached in such a way that any prefix can be omitted</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Remember the filters are there to filter any incoming request or outcoming response, so actually the flow is something like this.

client -----> request ---- > filter ----> servlet dispather ----> resources

So now, unfortunately the request will be intercepted by the filter no matter is the resource exist or not, and this happens before the servlet dispather can  get the request and get realize that the resource doesn't exist.

I hope, this explanation can answer your question.

Thanks.